# Installing and maintaining email server

Tags: email, postfix, vps, dovecot

Until now, I've been using managed shared hosting, but recently I've been seriously considering moving everything to a VPS, such as Linode. The one thing that has me really hesitating is that I  must have a externally accessible email service as well. I've done a bit of research and I have no problem installing Postfix/Dovecot/Exim (plus clamav and spamassassin). But it worries me that it may be a lot more difficult to install and maintain than I expected. The only thing that seems to make this difficult is that I have four or five domains, each with their own email addresses that I want to carry over to the new setup, and I want all client traffic to be encrypted.

So how difficult is it to get an email server up and running, that's accessible via external email clients (SMTP and POP3 -- no IMAP), works with SSL/TLS, and supports multiple domains?